# Definitive distinction between Greek Heir κληρονόμον ("klēronómos") in Hebrews 1:2 versus an Ivri Heir יוֹרֵ֥שׁ ("Yoresh") in Genesis 15:3?

Tags: genesis, word-study, hebrews, definition

Was the Greek term for [Heir] : κληρονόμον ("klēronómos") - always associated with divine inheritance, similar to the Ivri term for [The Heir] : הַיֹּרֵשׁ֙ ("Ha-Yoresh") | **[Heir] יוֹרֵ֥שׁ ("Yoresh")** also used in divine prophecy?

**What are the definitive distinctions between Greek Heir κληρονόμον ("klēronómos") in Hebrews 1:2 versus an Ivri Heir יוֹרֵ֥שׁ ("Yoresh") in Genesis 15:3?**

Answer (score 1):

Genesis 15:

> 3
> And Abram said, “You have given me no children; so a servant in my household will be my **heir**.”

The Hebrew word for "heir" is H3423 (Yoresh). LXX uses G2818 (klēronómos) which is the same Greek word used in
Hebrews 1:

> 2
> but in these last days he has spoken to us by his Son, whom he appointed **heir** of all things, and through whom also he made the universe.

Was the Greek term for [Heir] : κληρονόμον ("klēronómos") - always associated with divine inheritance?

No, not necessarily. Galatians 4:

> 1 What I am saying is that as long as an **heir** is underage, he is no different from a slave, although he owns the whole estate.

This one is about earthly inheritance.